# Can I include Java constant value in AsciiDoctor document?

Tags: java, asciidoc, asciidoctor

For example, lets have a Java constant in some class

```
public class MyClass{
  public static final String ENDPOINT="http://example.com"
}
```

and lets try to describe that class in AsciiDoctor (corporate docs reasons)

```
==== My class

..... some descripton ..... 
It is exposed trough http://example.com
```

Now every time I change the endpoint, I have to update docs manually as well (IDE find-and-replace will do the trick obviously). Is there a way to include Java constant into the AsciiDoc so I don't have to copy its value into the docs?

I would gladly see something like `{import my.package.MyClass#ENDPOINT}` or something similiar.

Comment: You can use attributes in Asciidoc, then you only have to define the constant once for your documentation (e.g. in the header of the doc, or as a parameter when building the docs. You could also generate the Asciidoc from Java code, and then use the constant, but that seems a bit exotic to me. Alternatively, you could define the constant in your build, and then have your build generate the source code with the necessary constant, and build your documentation using that value.

Comment: But is there a syntax to include such contant like `whole.package.MyClass#myConstant`? Docs are built in the pipeline in java anyway in my case so I can easily include system as a dependency. The only thing is, how to refer to it?

Comment: Or maybe I can write my own preprocessor of some kind to do just that?

Comment: AsciiDoctor is Ruby or JavaScript based (AsciiDoctor J is wrapper around JRuby), so it's unlikely, and if there were it would probably be explicitly spelled out in the documentation.

Comment: Understaood, thanks Mark for little bit of insight

Comment: That said, AsciiDoctor (and Asciidoctor J) has several extension points, so maybe you could write something custom to do it, but personally I would rather drive it from my build system populating both my Java code and AsciiDoctor attributes then adding something to AsciiDoctor to parse Java code.

Comment: There is https://blog.mrhaki.com/2014/04/awesome-asciidoc-include-partial-parts.html but that is line based, you can't do part of a line.

Answer (score 1):

One other solution is to use the include-pattern of asciidoctor which is described here. https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/directives/include-tagged-regions/

In short.

Define a tagged region:

```
public class MyClass{
  //tag::endpointdefinition[]
  public static final String ENDPOINT="http://example.com"
  //end::endpointdefinition[]
}
```

include it your document

```
[source,java]
----
include::pathYourFile.java[tag=endpointdefinition] 
----
```

To optimize it a little bit you could break your lines different int the java file and place the tag definition on that. You could also remove the source around including the java file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a shell script (PERL, whatever) that greps your Java code for a regex something like `'class (\w+).*ENDPOINT="([^"]+)'`, sending the results to an include file (`./endpoints.adoc`) using `':\1_endpoint: \2'`, thus:

```
:MyClass_endpoint: http://example.com
:MyOtherClass_endpoint: http://other.example.com
```

Then, at the top of your AsciiDoc file insert: `include::endpoints.adoc[]`

and then refer to `{MyClass_endpoint}` and `{MyOtherClass_endpoint}` in the body.

Then, simply run the script as part of your toolchain prior to calling AsciiDoctor.